# container:start Not a valid key: start at Scalatra-website-examples/deployment

Tags: scala, heroku, deployment, sbt

I'm trying to follow [this](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-website-examples/tree/master/2.4/deployment/scalatra-heroku) tutorial about scalatra deployment.

But I get error on `> container:start`, I very new to scala and have no idea what to do, googling result tells me to setup xsbt-web-plugin, but is it right? isn't examples need to fully independent for such custom dependencies or it is scala way?

upd(console output):

```
➜  scalatra-heroku git:(master) sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/user1/folder1/scalatra-website-examples/2.4/deployment/scalatra-heroku/project
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/user1/folder1/scalatra-website-examples/2.4/deployment/scalatra-heroku/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[warn] there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Set current project to Heroku Example (in build file:/Users/user1/folder1/scalatra-website-examples/2.4/deployment/scalatra-heroku/)
> container:start
[error] Not a valid key: start (similar: state, startYear, target)
[error] container:start
[error]
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you post the output?

Comment: @codefinger sorry, didn't notify you, updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that README is messed up. Try this example instead:
https://github.com/kissaten/scalatra-heroku

And you can always follow this guide:
http://scalatra.org/2.4/guides/deployment/heroku.html